# Why compile error? excel vba reference to outlook

Tags: excel, vba

This 'archiveOutlookFolder' code works fine until I run other code that removes/re-adds a reference to outlook. After unloading/loading Outlook I get a compile error on the objFolder.MoveTo objDestFolder line.

I have to unload/load Outlook because different people have different versions of outlook throughout the office. So, to prevent errors, if the workbook has a version loaded, it's unloaded, then the user's version is loaded.

To reiterate: after unloading/loading Outlook I start getting a compile error on the 'objFolder.MoveTo objDestFolder' line of the 'archiveOutlookFolder' sub.

Any assistance resolving this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Private Sub LoadOutlook()

Application.Run "UnloadOutlook"

    On Error GoTo unable2Load

    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile "MSOUTL.OLB"

    Exit Sub

unable2Load:

If Err.Number = 32813 Then Exit Sub

If Err.Number = 48 Then'for some reason 16 won't load without specific reference
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\MSOUTL.OLB"
Exit Sub
End If

    MsgBox err.number & vblf & vblf & err.description

End Sub

Private Sub UnloadOutlook()

    On Error GoTo unable2Unload

    Dim References As Object
    Set References = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References
    References.Remove References("Outlook")

    Exit Sub

unable2Unload:

If Err.Number = 9 Then Exit Sub 'already unloaded

MsgBox err.number & vblf & vblf & err.description

End Sub


Private Sub archiveOutlookFolder()

on error goto errHandler

Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim objSourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objFolder As Folder
Dim AAfolderToMove As String
Dim PNAToMove As String
Dim eventFolderTomove As String
Dim foundEventFolder As Boolean

Dim olAAfolders As Outlook.Folder
Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folder

PNAToMove = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("cleanpna").Value

On Error Resume Next
Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If objOutlook Is Nothing Then
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If

Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olAAfolders = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Audits-Actuals")

foundEventFolder = False

For Each olFolder In olAAfolders.Folders
    If InStr(olFolder.Name, PNAToMove) > 0 Then
    eventFolderTomove = olFolder.Name
    foundEventFolder = True
    Exit For
    End If
Next olFolder

If foundEventFolder = False Then
MsgBox "I did not find an Outlook folder for this event to move to Past events. Please move manually.", vbCritical, "Audits\Actuals"
Exit Sub
End If

   Set objSourceFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
   Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Audits-Actuals").Folders(eventFolderTomove)
   Set objDestFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("PAST Audits-Actuals")

   objFolder.MoveTo objDestFolder

   Set objDestFolder = Nothing
   Set objFolder = Nothing
   Set objSourceFolder = Nothing
   Set objOutlook = Nothing
   Set objDestFolder = Nothing

   Exit Sub

errhandler:

subName = "archiveOutlookFolder"
thisErrNum = Err.Number
thisErrDes = Err.Description

Call sendErrorAlert

End Sub
```

Comment: When your coding is done, change Outlook specific variables to `As Object` and you are reference free, but remember to define any Outlook constants with `Private Const`, e.g. `Private Const olFolderInbox = 6`

Comment: Thank you so much, @PatricK ! This is fantastic that I don't need references! I tried setting as Const but must me doing something wrong?

Comment: Thank you so much, @PatricK ! This is fantastic that I don't need references! I tried setting as Const but must me doing something wrong cuz  'Const objOutlook As Object = Outlook.Application' gives me 'variable not defined' but I can't figure out what variable to use. I was able to go with 'Dim objOutlook As Object' & 'Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")' but then I get a 'variable not defined' on 'olFolderInbox' &, again, can't figure out which variable to use (both object & folder throw mismatch errors). Could you maybe post an example of your solution so I can check it out?

Comment: Oh, what I meant is those `Dim xxx As Outlook.yyy` to be `Dim xxx As Object`, and those builtin constants starting with `ol`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```
Private Const olFolderInbox = 6

Private Sub archiveOutlookFolder()

On Error GoTo errhandler

Dim AA_FOLDER As String
Dim DEST_FOLDER As String

AA_FOLDER = "Audits-Actuals"
DEST_FOLDER = "PAST Audits-Actuals"

Dim objOutlook As Object ' Outlook.Application
Dim objNamespace As Object ' Outlook.Namespace
Dim objSourceFolder As Object ' Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objDestFolder As Object ' Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objFolder As Object ' Outlook.Folder
Dim olAAfolders As Object ' Outlook.Folder
Dim olFolder As Object ' Outlook.Folder

Dim AAfolderToMove As String
Dim PNAToMove As String
Dim eventFolderTomove As String
Dim foundEventFolder As Boolean

PNAToMove = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("cleanpna").Value

On Error Resume Next
Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo errhandler
If objOutlook Is Nothing Then
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If

tryAgain:
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objSourceFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olAAfolders = objSourceFolder.Parent.Folders(AA_FOLDER)

foundEventFolder = False

For Each olFolder In olAAfolders.Folders
    If InStr(olFolder.Name, PNAToMove) > 0 Then
        eventFolderTomove = olFolder.Name
        foundEventFolder = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next olFolder

If Not foundEventFolder And AA_FOLDER = "Audits-Actuals" Then
AA_FOLDER = "PAST Audits-Actuals"
DEST_FOLDER = "Audits-Actuals"
GoTo tryAgain
End If

If Not foundEventFolder Then
MsgBox "I did not find an Outlook folder for this event to move automatically. Please move manually.", vbCritical, "Audits\Actuals"
Exit Sub
End If

Set objFolder = objSourceFolder.Parent.Folders(AA_FOLDER).Folders(eventFolderTomove)
Set objDestFolder = objSourceFolder.Parent.Folders(DEST_FOLDER)

If Not (objFolder Is Nothing And objDestFolder Is Nothing) Then objFolder.MoveTo objDestFolder

Set olAAfolders = Nothing
Set objNamespace = Nothing
Set objDestFolder = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objSourceFolder = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing

Exit Sub

errhandler:

MsgBox Err.Number & vbLf & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this in Outlook, but some changes to your **`archiveOutlookFolder`** Sub. Since you have hard coded some folder names, you better check if they became Nothing during Set, if it's Nothing, you may want to let user pick a folder?

About `If InStr(olFolder.Name, PNAToMove) > 0 Then`, this means you want to do something when some part of the Outlook folder name **contains** the value of PNAToMove.

```
Private Const olFolderInbox = 6

Private Sub archiveOutlookFolder()

    Const AA_FOLDER As String = "Audits-Actuals"
    Const DEST_FOLDER As String = "PAST Audits-Actuals"

    On Error GoTo errhandler

    Dim objOutlook As Object ' Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Object ' Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objSourceFolder As Object ' Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objDestFolder As Object ' Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objFolder As Object ' Folder
    Dim AAfolderToMove As String
    Dim PNAToMove As String
    Dim eventFolderTomove As String
    Dim foundEventFolder As Boolean

    Dim olAAfolders As Object ' Outlook.Folder
    Dim olFolder As Object ' Outlook.Folder

    PNAToMove = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("cleanpna").Value

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If objOutlook Is Nothing Then
        Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If

    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objSourceFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) ' <-- Make use of this!
    'Set olAAfolders = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Audits-Actuals")
    Set olAAfolders = objSourceFolder.Parent.Folders(AA_FOLDER) ' ("Audits-Actuals")

    foundEventFolder = False

    For Each olFolder In olAAfolders.Folders
        If InStr(olFolder.Name, PNAToMove) > 0 Then
            eventFolderTomove = olFolder.Name
            foundEventFolder = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next olFolder

    If Not foundEventFolder Then ' If foundEventFolder = False Then
        MsgBox "I did not find an Outlook folder for this event to move to Past events. Please move manually.", vbCritical, "Audits\Actuals"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Set objSourceFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) ' Moved this up!
    'Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Audits-Actuals").Folders(eventFolderTomove)
    Set objFolder = objSourceFolder.Parent.Folders(AA_FOLDER).Folders(eventFolderTomove)
    'Set objDestFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("PAST Audits-Actuals")
    Set objDestFolder = objSourceFolder.Parent.Folders(DEST_FOLDER)

   If Not (objFolder Is Nothing And objDestFolder Is Nothing) Then objFolder.MoveTo objDestFolder

   Set objDestFolder = Nothing
   Set objFolder = Nothing
   Set objSourceFolder = Nothing
   Set objOutlook = Nothing
   Set objDestFolder = Nothing

   Exit Sub

errhandler:

    subName = "archiveOutlookFolder"
    thisErrNum = Err.Number
    thisErrDes = Err.Description

    Call sendErrorAlert

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, @PatricK! (Yes, I want to move the Outlook folder with name containing the value of PNAToMove). I'm still getting the same errors. (1) olFolderInbox = var not defined. I tried both Folder and Object but get mismatch on both. (2) objFolder.MoveTo = compile error/method or data member not found. I tried manualy restoring the reference just to see if it would then work but nope. Any ideas? Thanks again for helping me with this.

Comment: I missed the const declaration for the olFolderInbox and fixed that, sorry about that! Now I just get the compile error on .moveto @patricK

Comment: Hmm... also getting err 13/type mismatch on this line 'Set objFolder = objSourceFolder.Parent.Folders(AA_FOLDER).Folders(eventFolderTomove)' @patricK

Comment: I figured it out... the objFolder needed to be declared as an Object not a Folder... fixed both errors.

Comment: You may want to start using `Option Explicit` for all coding in future. In VBE, Tools -> Options, Editor tab, Code Settings, tick **Require Variable Declaration**.

Comment: Hi, PatricK. Yes, I am using that for all my code. Everything was declared but just not as the right thing.